# typescript virtual project errors in visual studio 2015 projects

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I am getting these weird errord when I try to build my project through Visual Studio 2015  searched a lot on the internet and tried many things but with no luck. Could any one please help me with the issue

> Error TS2307  Build:Cannot find module
>   './router_preloader'. GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli  C:\TFS\ICTDevelopment\NET\GLD.CMS.SOA\GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli\node_modules\@angular\router\src\router_module.d.ts    13
>
> Error TS2430  Build:Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends
>   interface
>   'Uint8Array'. GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli  C:\TFS\ICTDevelopment\NET\GLD.CMS.SOA\GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli\typings\globals\node\index.d.ts    415
>
> Error TS2307  Cannot find module './util/lang'.   TypeScript Virtual
>   Projects  C:\TFS\ICTDevelopment\NET\GLD.CMS.SOA\GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli\node_modules\@angular\core\src\core_private_export.d.ts    38  Active
>
> Error TS2307  Cannot find module
>   './router_preloader'. C:\TFS\ICTDevelopment\NET\GLD.CMS.SOA\GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli\node_modules\@angular\router\src\index.d.ts    16  Active
>
> Error TS2307  Cannot find module './router_preloader'. TS2430 Interface
>   'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.   Types of
>   property 'fill' are incompatible.
>       Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number)
>   => this'.
>         Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'this'. TypeScript Virtual
>   Projects  C:\TFS\ICTDevelopment\NET\GLD.CMS.SOA\GLD.CMS.SOA.WebCli\typings\globals\node\index.d.ts    415 Active

my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"

  ]
}
```

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "gld-soa",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "typings": "typings",
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" "
      },
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",


        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",    
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "0.19.39",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.25",

        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",

        "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.17"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "2.0.3",
        "typings": "^1.4.0",
        "rimraf": "2.2.8",
        "lodash": "^4.13.1"
      }
    }
```